# Is there anyway to obtain the full abstract from a 'PUBmed' article using java code

Tags: java, abstract, pubmed

Is there anyway to obtain the full abstract from a 'PUBmed' article using java APIs

Comment: Usually options are 1) REST API (best) or 2) selenium-like solution.

Comment: Could you please share the REST API Reference

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if there is one or not. You might try looking at the PUBmed site.